# I have a question on PDEs

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

My professor told me that the following expression is true, which is very hard to prove. The expression is

$x_tt_yy_x=-1$,

where $x$ is a function of $t$ and $y$,  $y$ is a function of $x$ and $t$ and $t$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. Can anyone give me a clue to show this relation.

Comment: I think you can look up the triple product rule?

Comment: So is each function completely defined in terms of the other two functions?

Comment: For instance, $x_t=1/t_x$, $t_y=1/y_t$ and $y_x=1/x_y$ like that

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule#Derivation

Comment: Oh yes yes, Thanks Aminopterin and Camille